# kubernetes giving CrashLoopBackOff error while creating pods

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, orchestration

I'm creating a pod of node container, and it is giving *CrashLoopBackOff* error.

**kubectl get pods**

[image]

**kubectl describe pod test-node3**

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Commands like `kubectl get` and `kubectl describe` should usually write out text content to the console, not images.  Can you replace these images with the actual output of the commands, and provide the source code (_e.g._, deployment YAML files) necessary to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your container does not have a long running process. The main process in the container is exiting with exit code 0 which usually means that the process has terminated successfully. You can see it in the kubectl describe output you have shared.

```
Reason: Completed 
Exit Code: 0
```

Comment: but this container is running fine with docker.

Comment: What is the command you use to start docker container? You probably are specifying an entrypoint on the command line and so it must be working.

Comment: docker run -t <image_name> -p 3000:3000

Comment: it opens container in interactive mode

Comment: That is because you are using `-t` option which allocates a pseudo-tty. Try `docker run <image_name> -p 3000:3000`, this is what will happen when you run the container using pod.

Comment: yeah true, so. how to run pod in interactive mode or in background mode?

Answer (score 2):

You can add command as below so that pod will remain in running state.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp-pod
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp-container
    image: busybox
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo Hello Kubernetes! && sleep 3600']
```

Ref: [Doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/)

Answer (score 1):

Once Pod is assigned to a node by scheduler, kubelet starts creating containers using container runtime. There are three possible states of containers: Waiting, Running and Terminated.

**Terminated: Indicates that the container completed its execution and has stopped running**.

**A container enters into this when it has successfully completed execution or when it has failed for some reason.** Regardless, a **reason and exit code is displayed**, as well as the container’s start and finish time.

On your screenshot its clear that container inside pod is running to completion with its work done, with exit code 0 as below snippet

```
  State:          Terminated
    Reason:       Completed
    Exit Code:    0
```

**You should either add a long running process to your container or define `restartPolicy: Never` on pod definition.**

**Tested your image with adding correct restart policy and POD runs correctly to completion with no crash**

```
kubectl run test --image=abhishekk27/kube-pub:new --restart=Never

$ kubectl get pods
NAME      READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
test      0/1     Completed   0          8m12s
```

yaml genrated :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: test
  name: test
spec:
  containers:
  - image: abhishekk27/kube-pub:new
    name: test
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Never
```

**Result**:

```
$ kubectl describe pod test
Name:         test
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         dlv-k8s-node-1/131.160.200.104
Start Time:   Fri, 17 Jan 2020 09:45:00 +0000
Labels:       run=test
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Succeeded
IP:           10.244.1.12
IPs:
  IP:  10.244.1.12
Containers:
  test:
    Container ID:   docker://b335e5fef022dced824f85ba2bfe4c024608c9b5463599eb36591a14d709786d
    Image:          abhishekk27/kube-pub:new
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://abhishekk27/kube-pub@sha256:6a696bd733edaa48b9be781960f4ee178d16f1c9aea51e53bd0f54326a3d05b1
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Fri, 17 Jan 2020 09:45:48 +0000
      Finished:     Fri, 17 Jan 2020 09:45:48 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-7f4mt (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-7f4mt:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-7f4mt
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age    From                     Message
  ----    ------     ----   ----                     -------
  Normal  Scheduled  6m50s  default-scheduler        Successfully assigned default/test to dlv-k8s-node-1
  Normal  Pulling    6m46s  kubelet, dlv-k8s-node-1  Pulling image "abhishekk27/kube-pub:new"
  Normal  Pulled     5m58s  kubelet, dlv-k8s-node-1  Successfully pulled image "abhishekk27/kube-pub:new"
  Normal  Created    5m58s  kubelet, dlv-k8s-node-1  Created container test
  Normal  Started    5m58s  kubelet, dlv-k8s-node-1  Started container test
```

Comment: The status is showing completed after running command

***kubectl create -f app/node.yml***
Do I need to run more command to run this pod?

Comment: Is this a genuine solution?

Comment: if you want a infinite running container you need to update your image to have a task which is running in a loop ... like something very simple as adding a infinite loop will help .. try this yaml  in your test as a test and you can see this will keep your container up infinitely ..  `apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: test
  name: test
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - /bin/bash
    - -c
    - "while true; do :; done"
    image: abhishekk27/kube-pub:new
    name: test`